# Vue Modal buttons moving to weird places in IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, vue.js

I have a modal that i am using for error messages being displayed to the user. This works fine when testing in all browsers apart from IE. In IE the 'OK' button that is used to close the modal is moved over to the right so it is being displayed half within the modal and half not.

[image: Here is the error being displayed in IE]

Here is the code where this Modal is being created.

```
<template>
<transition name="modal" v-if="show">
<div class="modal-mask">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal-container">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Error</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
         {{ error }}
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
         <button class="btn btn-danger modal-default-button" @click="dismissError">
            OK
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</transition>
</template>



<script>
import { ErrorService } from '../../services/ErrorService';

export default {
data(){
    return {
        show: false,
        error: null
    }
},
methods: {
    dismissError(){
        this.show = false;
    }
},
created() {
    ErrorService.$on('error', (data) => {
        if(data){
            this.show = true;
            this.error = data;
        }
    })
},
destroyed() {
    ErrorService.$off('error');
},
}
</script>


<style scoped>

h2{
margin: auto;
}

.modal-mask {
position: fixed;
z-index: 9998;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
display: table;
transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
width: 300px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 20px 30px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
transition: all .3s ease;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modal-body .modal-footer {
 margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-default-button {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
 } 

 .modal-enter .modal-container,
 .modal-leave-active .modal-container {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1);

 </style>
```

I have found quite a few issues with IE while developing this App, cant seem to find a work around to this one, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have `btn btn-danger` classes in your button. They look like Bootstrap classes. Are you sure Bootstrap is not messing up your styles?

Comment: It could be, i was presuming it was more an issue with IE though as everything has been working fine in other browsers

Comment: @Sunley95 Which version of IE?

Comment: Based on your code I can't directly tell what could be wrong. You should probably check the devtools on IE to see how the classes are affecting the positioning of the button.

Comment: @ShannonYoung I am using IE11

Comment: Are you sure it's not being messed up by some parent component? I've just tested it on IE7-11 and the OK button is centered in all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be with `margin: 0 auto;` simply removing this has sort of solved the issue, the button still appears to be more to the right than in other browsers but it is within the bounds of the Modal now. This fix is a lot better than it was although still not perfect.